# Tableview cell button selection error

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

I have a tableview that contains a button in the left of cell. the run works well and when i select a button a made it change its image background. The problem is when I select a button[ButtonOne selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k57bP.jpg) , it select other buttons when I scroll tableview down, [Other buttons selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji6H8.jpg) my code is this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlayerCell
    cell.BtnAdd.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.BtnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CreateTeamTwo.PlayerAdded(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return cell  
}

func PlayerAdded(sender: UIButton){
    // let buttonTag = sender.tag
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_buy_minus.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)        
}
```

can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one Array to store selected indexPaths Buttons tags. and in selector methods store all the sender tags and reload the tableView. and in cellForRow method check if current indexpath is contain in selected array then show minus image otherwise show plus image.

```
var selected = [Int]()


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlayerCell
    cell.BtnAdd.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.BtnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CreateTeamTwo.PlayerAdded(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    if selected.contains(indexPath.row) {
        cell.btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_buy_minus.png"), forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        // here set the plus image
        cell.btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_buy_plus.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    return cell
}

func PlayerAdded(sender: UIButton){
    selected.append(sender.tag)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```